# fire BroadcastReveiver Notifications after android reboot

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

i im actualy trying to make an android application that fire notifications for users using :

NOTIFICATION MANAGER ==>  BROADCAST RECEIVER

however , after the system reboot the notifications don't work.

FYI : i put the INTENT FILTERS to the BROADCAST MANAGER LIKE THAT :

```
    <receiver
        android:name=".AlarmReceiver"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true"
        android:permission="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

THE BROADCAST RECEIVER CODE :

```
       public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

       @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        long when = System.currentTimeMillis();
        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)     context
                .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, DetailsNotification.class);
        notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,
                notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);


        Uri alarmSound = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);

        NotificationCompat.Builder mNotifyBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
                context).setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notification)
                .setContentTitle("Alarm Fired")
                .setContentText("Events a To be   PErformed").setSound(alarmSound)
                .setAutoCancel(true).setWhen(when)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                .setVibrate(new long[]{1000, 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000});
        notificationManager.notify((int) System.currentTimeMillis(),        mNotifyBuilder.build());

    }

 }
```

THE MAIN ACTIVITY CODE :

```
        Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, Hours);
            calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, Minutes);
            calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
            Intent intent1 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AlarmReceiver.class);
            intent1.putExtra("wache","test_test");
            intent1.setAction(Long.toString(System.currentTimeMillis()));
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(MainActivity.this, 0,intent1, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
            AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) MainActivity.this.getSystemService(MainActivity.this.ALARM_SERVICE);
            am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),     AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pendingIntent);

            Log.d("youngSaid","notification 1 programmé a :  " + String.valueOf(MainActivity.Hours) + "   " + MainActivity.Minutes);


            Calendar calendar2 = Calendar.getInstance();
            calendar2.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, Hours2);
            calendar2.set(Calendar.MINUTE, Minutes2);
            calendar2.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
            Intent intent2 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AlarmReceiver.class);
            intent2.putExtra("wache","azerazer");
            intent2.setAction(Long.toString(System.currentTimeMillis()));
            PendingIntent pendingIntent2 = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(MainActivity.this, 0,intent2, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
            AlarmManager am2 = (AlarmManager) MainActivity.this.getSystemService(MainActivity.this.ALARM_SERVICE);
            am2.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar2.getTimeInMillis(),     AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pendingIntent2);
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Notification Lancé", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            Log.d("youngSaid","notification 2 programmé a :  " + String.valueOf(MainActivity.Hours2) + "   " + MainActivity.Minutes2);
        }
    });
```

please HELP :) 
BR

Answer (score 0):

You need boot permission in manifest.

```
<receiver
    android:name=".AlarmReceiver"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:exported="true"
    /** The uses permission is defined in Manifest not in receiver*/
    android:permission="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Comment: thanks for your replay : i already have it 
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />

Comment: When i lanch it manualy ot works . After the phone reboot didn't . How can i log it ?